# toLocaleString incorrect in Firefox for AEDT

Tags: javascript, datetime, firefox, date-formatting

In the *Australia/Sydney* time zone, Firefox seems to give an incorrect time for `toLocaleString` on dates:

`new Date("2019-04-04T01:12:38.553309+00:00").toLocaleString()` gives `"4/4/2019, 11:12:38 AM"`.

`new Date("2019-04-04T01:12:38.553309+00:00").toString()` gives correct result `"Thu Apr 04 2019 12:12:38 GMT+1100 (AEDT)"`.

I've been able to reproduce this on my phone as well as my computer. I asked a colleague to test, and Firefox gave the correct output on his computer.

Chromium gives the correct time for `toLocaleString`.

Is this a bug in Firefox? Do I have some misconfiguration?

I assume the correct approach here is to use a 3rd party library like *date-fns* to format my Dates instead.

Update: for now I have switched to using `dateFns.format(timestamp, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')`. We don't have any US customers anyway.

Comment: @Kaiido I have my computer set to use the US locale (to get the correct keyboard layout), but the Australia/Sydney timezone.

Comment: Actually it should be 12, but yes.

Comment: And forcing it like this: `new Date("2019-04-04T01:12:38.553309+00:00").toLocaleString('en-AU', {timeZone:'Australia/Sydney'})` what does it give? From mine I get `"04/04/2019, 12:12:38 pm"`.

Comment: I get the same, which implies that my timezone is somehow set incorrectly. Both Chrome and Firefox give `-660` as the result to `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`, however.

Comment: I think this is because of privacy.resistFingerprinting setting in the newest firefox versions. Date is completely broken because of it in exchange for a little bit of privacy.